# How to limit the result of a query having array in it for MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb

I have the document in MongoDB like --

```
{
name: "Myname",
Auth: "myAuth",
Books:[{
        b_name: "bookname",
        b_type: "tech",
        datetime: "datetime"
     }],
dept: "IT"
}
```

Now If I just want to get the name field based upon filter condition, I can query like --

```
db.books.find( { dept: "IT" } , { Myname:1, Auth:1,  _id:0 } )
```

But if I want to get one single field as well as one of the array field in the array `"Books"`, how do I query the `MongoDB`.

I want something like --

```
db.books.find( { dept: "IT" } , { Myname:1, Auth:1, Books.b_name:1,  _id:0 } )
```

The above query will not work.

Comment: Is the issue that you want to limit the number of array elements returned?  Or is it that you have a syntax error in your query?  If your problem is the former, use [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)

Comment: @numbers1311407 $slice is only relevant where the position in the array is **known** Otherwise the use of projection and the *match* operator is recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection attributes are JSON/doccument  fields . You have no  field like Myname . Secondly you have to use quotes for sub document like 'Books.b_name'

**Query :**

```
db.books.find( { dept: "IT" } , { name:1, 'Auth':1, 'Books.b_name':1, _id:0 } ) ;
```

**Output :**

```
{ "name" : "Myname", "Auth" : "myAuth", "Books" : [ { "b_name" : "bookname" } ] }
```

Comment: I would suggest anyone who is able to review the edit history as you seem to have a history of editing your answers to copt the results of others. It is sad that you seem to be so desperate like this.

Comment: Point being "for the reader" this poster has a history of submitting a wrong answer **early** and then copying the correct answer from somebody else. As can be seen in the comments, the lack of understanding extends to **not understanding** how to tag another user who has commented in the post properly. Please consider in evaluating your vote.

Comment: Sumeet, Yes I just make a typo in the name field. You are correct and also I tried your query with the quote and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Neil, I don't know what you are talking about posting wrong answer and then correcting by copying. What do you mean by that???